# Mimo ICAP codec, does not work with HTTP 403

Tags: netty

We are using the http://icap.mimo.ch/ netty ICAP client. When a server responds with HTTP 403, the client seems to be off on reading the HTTP headers. Any help appreciated.

**The logs from mimo codec**

> IcapClient HostIP absoluteFilePath
>
> SKIP_CONTROL_CHARS-------
>
> READ_ICAP_INITIAL_STATE-------
>
> READ_ICAP_HEADER_STATE-------
>
> READ_HTTP_REQUEST_INITIAL_AND_HEADERS-------
>
> ```
>     8 Feb, 2013 4:15:53 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
> WARNING: EXCEPTION, please implement com.chunk.IcapClientHandler.exceptionCaught() for proper handling.
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: FORBIDDEN
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62)
>     at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.ReadHttpRequestInitialAndHeadersState.execute(ReadHttpRequestInitialAndHeadersState.java:52)
>     at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapMessageDecoder.decode(IcapMessageDecoder.java:98)
>     at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapMessageDecoder.decode(IcapMessageDecoder.java:1)
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
> ```

**Packet capture of the response:**

> ICAP/1.0 200 OK
>
> Encapsulated: req-hdr=0, res-hdr=0, res-body=176
>
> Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 09:35:39 GMT
>
> Service: Somethin Systems Somethin Systems DLP SDK ICAP Server 1.0
>
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>
> Content-Type: text/xml
>
> Content-Length: 1118
>
> Server: Somethin Systems Somethin Systems DLP SDK ICAP Server 1.0
>
> Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 09:35:39 GMT
>
> 45e

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
    <Action>3</Action>
</Results>
```

Above xml is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "req-hdr=0" was not allowed in the ICAP response. In other words the issue was more with the ICAP server sending non-conformant response.